# How to calculate rectangle 'chord' after rotation?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

I am no mathematician so please forgive me for using wrong terms.

I am looking to calculate the length of a segment of a rectangle according to its rotation around one of its vertices.
For instance:

[After 30deg rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spfp3.jpg)

I'm interested in knowing the length of the red segment.

I came with a plot like this with a $30\times10$ rectangle (deg on absciss axis and length on ordinates axis):

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxQEn.jpg)

It ressembles nothing that I am aware of.
I made some searches on the Internet but failed to find functions that could look like it. My guess is I should use trigonometry since it depends on the rectangle properties (30 and 10) and the angle.

Any suggestion is more than welcome!

Comment: Is lengthy of blue(including red line) line equals to 30?

Comment: Sorry that might not have been clear enough. The blue line has no length. It is just a way to symbolize the origin (angle 0). The rectangle rotates around its vertex situated on this blue line.

Comment: If the breadth of the rectangle is 'a', then by rotating by 45 degrees, the length of the red line would become $a\sqrt{2}$. But, the picture makes it look like you have rotated it through 30 degrees instead.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I am more looking for a general function that could calculate the length of that red line, not for that 45 degree specific case. You are right for the angle! I am going to edit my post straight away. Sorry about that.

Comment: The red segment is $10 / \cos \alpha$ where $10$ is the short side, for $\alpha$ up to the angle that brings the opposite corner on the blue line. For the $10:30$ rectangle that would be $\arctan 3 \approx 72^\circ$, beyond which the red segment starts to decrease and the formula changes.

Comment: Thank you very much @dxiv. If I understand correctly, the length should be $d/cos(a)$ where d is the short side and a is angle at which the blue line is parallel to the long side of the rectangle? Shouldn't this be varying depending on the rotation angle though?

Comment: $\alpha$ in my previous comment is the angle between the blue line and the "raised" short side above it, which is precisely the angle of rotation (unless of course I completely misread what you meant).

Comment: Thank you again for your input! I tried with a few angles but I get bad results. For instance a rotation of 50 degrees should give me 15.557 but $10/cos(50)$ gives 10.3631. Am I doing something wrong? My explanation must be too messy, I feel very sorry about that. In my illustration, the rectangle rotates anti-clockwise around the top left vertex (on the blue line). What I am looking for is the length of the segment from that apex to the other side of the rectangle, overlapping the blue line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a right triangle with sides $x$ and $y$, with
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{h} = \tan(\varphi) \\
\frac{y}{w} = \tan(90° - \varphi)
\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}
x = h \tan(\varphi) \\
y = w \tan(90° -\varphi)
\end{cases}$$
except that $\lvert x \rvert$ is limited to at most $w^2$, and $\lvert y \rvert$ is limited to at most $h^2$; in other words,
$$\begin{cases}
x^2 = \min(w^2, h^2 \tan^2(\varphi)) \\
y^2 = \min(h^2, w^2 \tan^2(90° - \varphi))
\end{cases}$$
where $\min$ operator just picks the smaller one, limiting $x^2$ to at most $w^2$, and $y^2$ to at most $h^2$.

The desired length, $f(\varphi)$, is the length of the hypotenuse,
$$f(\varphi) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
i.e., in degrees:
$$f(\varphi) = \sqrt{\min\left( w^2, h^2 \tan^2(\varphi) \right) + \min\left( h^2, w^2 \tan^2(90° - \varphi) \right) }$$ 
or, in radians:
$$f(\varphi) = \sqrt{\min\left( w^2, h^2 \tan^2(\varphi), \right) + \min\left( h^2, w^2 \tan^2(\pi/2 - \varphi) \right) }$$

If you use Gnuplot, you can draw this using

```
set samples 2000
set xlabel "degrees"
minsqr(a, b) = (a*a <= b*b) ? a*a : b*b;
f(x) = sqrt( minsqr(w, h*tan(x)) + minsqr(h, w*tan(0.5*pi-x)))

h=10.0 ; w=30.0 ; plot [0:360] f(x*pi/180.0) notitle w lines
```

The `set samples 2000` tells Gnuplot to calculate the function at two thousand points. Current displays are so large, and the default number of samples so small, that the curve might seem to have extra features otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! Even though I am not sure how you got the first two equations, I get the expected results. I cannot thank you enough. On gnuplot I get the following:

[plot][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyGoV.jpg

Comment: On second thought, I found it. $tan(a)$ is the the opposite over the adjacent. Trivial trigonometry, silly me! Thank you again!

Comment: @LittleEndian: Yes, that is it exactly. You're welcome!